# Два лишних bottom-pixel

Tags: java, android, экран

У меня на телефоне, `Layout` и любой другой `View` выдаётся с одинаковым отступом в `1dp` от каждого края:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack" />
```

На нескольких эмуляторах, которые я пробовал, `marginBottom`, как и задано показывается размером в `3dp`. То есть у моего смартфона, в дополнении к его `480dp`, которые определяются `display.getHeight()` и `context.getHeight()` есть ещё два лишних `dp` внизу. Телефон на android 2.3.6.

Как определить, есть ли, и сколько в устройстве этих `extra-margins`?
[image: 3dp]
[image: 1dp]

То, что видно на смартфоне:
Левый скрин: marginBottom="3dp",
Правый скрин: marginBottom="1dp"
Новый проект по умолчанию. В проекте один RelativeLayout во весь экран с отступом.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имели ввиду под "extra-margins", учитывая, что dp относится ко всему экрану.

Comment: Если задать layout_height=480dp, то на телефоне, внизу экрана будут две дополнительные (невидимые) строки, которые можно обнаружить, задав layout_marginBottom=3dp. Эту странность я и обозвал extra-margins. Возможно у этого явления есть какое то точное название. Но мне оно неизвестно.

Comment: Во первых ничего не понятно. Во вторых какая у вас модель телефона?

Comment: Добавил скриншоты и пояснения к вопросу. Модель телефона вот: http://www.sealstech.co.uk/seals-ts3.php

Comment: Покажите следующую информация: у `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` поля density, densityDpi, heightPixels, widthPixels, scaledDensity. И скажите какие размеры у вашего главного лаяута в пикселах получаются.

Comment: m.density=1.0  
m.densityDpi=160.0  
m.heightPixels=480.0   
m.widthPixels=320.0   
m.scaledDensity=1.0   
root.getHeight=430 (без Title&Bar - 480)   
root.getWidth=320